# How to update a property in a deeply nested array of objects of unknown size using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a large array of objects that I need to recursively loop through and find the object I need to update by its `uid` and update the `data` property within that object. This array is of unknown size and shape. The following method works, but I was wondering if there was a "cleaner" way of doing this process.

The following code loops through every object / array until it finds an object with property `uid`, if this `uid` equals to the block I need to update, I set the `data` property of this object. Is there a better way to do this?

**Traversal Method**

```
      function traverse(x) {
        if (isArray(x)) {
          traverseArray(x)
        } else if ((typeof x === 'object') && (x !== null)) {
          traverseObject(x)
        } else {

        }
      }

      function traverseArray(arr) {
        arr.forEach(function (x) {
          traverse(x)
        })
      }

      function traverseObject(obj) {
        for (var key in obj) {

          // check if property is UID

          if (key == "uid") {

            // check if this uid is equal to what we are looking for

            if (obj[key] == "bcd") {

              // confirm it has a data property

              if (obj.hasOwnProperty('data')) {

                // assign new data to the data property

                obj['data'] = newData;
                return;
              }
            }
          }
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            traverse(obj[key])
          }
        }
      }

      function isArray(o) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Array]'
      }

      // usage:
      traverse(this.sections)
```

**Sample data**

```
this.sections = [
  {
    uid: "abc",
    layout: {
        rows: [
            {
                columns: [
                    {
                        blocks: [
                            {
                                uid: "bcd",
                                data: {
                                    content: "how are you?"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        blocks: [
                            {
                                uid: "cde",
                                data: {
                                    content: "how are you?"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                columns: [
                    {
                        blocks: [
                            {
                                uid: "def",
                                data: {
                                    content: "how are you?"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
  }
]
```

Is there a better way to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe convert to JSON and use JSONPath

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting with a generic object mapping function. It takes an object input, `o`, and a transformation to apply, `t` -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const mapObject = (o = {}, t = identity) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([ k, v ]) => [ k, t(v) ]))
```

Then build your recursive object mapping function using your shallow function. It takes an object to transform, `o`, and a transformation function, `t` -

```js
const recMapObject = (o = {}, t = identity) =>
  mapObject                       // <-- using mapObject
    ( o
    , node =>
        Array.isArray(node)      // <-- recur arrays
          ? node.map(x => recMapObject(t(x), t))
      : Object(node) === node    // <-- recur objects
          ? recMapObject(t(node), t)
      : t(node)
    )
```

Now you build the object transformation unique to your program using our recursive object mapping function. It takes the complex nested data, `graph`, the `uid` to match, and a transformation to apply to the matched node, `t` -

```js
const transformAtUid = (graph = {}, uid = "", t = identity) =>
  recMapObject              // <-- using recMapObject
    ( graph
    , (node = {}) =>
        node.uid === uid                    // if uid matches,
          ? { ...node, data: t(node.data) } // then transform node.data,
          : node                            // otherwise no change 
    )
```

The above step is important because it detangles the specific logic about `node.uid` and `node.data` from the rest of the generic object transformation code.

Now we call our function on the input, `data`, to transform nodes matching `node.uid` equal to `"bcd"` using an example transformation -

```js
const result =
  transformAtUid
    ( data                                // <-- input
    , "bcd"                               // <-- query
    , node => ({ ...node, changed: "x" }) // <-- transformation
    )

console.log(result)
```

Output -

```js
{
  "uid": "abc",
  "layout": {
    "rows": [
      {
        "columns": [
          {
            "blocks": [
              {
                "uid": "bcd",
                "data": {
                  "content": "how are you?",
                  "changed": "x"             // <-- transformed
                }
              }
            ]
          }

          // ...
}
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const mapObject = (o = {}, t = identity) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([ k, v ]) => [ k, t(v) ]))

const recMapObject = (o = {}, t = identity) =>
  mapObject                       // <-- using mapObject
    ( o
    , node =>
        Array.isArray(node)      // <-- recur arrays
          ? node.map(x => recMapObject(t(x), t))
      : Object(node) === node    // <-- recur objects
          ? recMapObject(t(node), t)
      : t(node)                  // <-- transform
    )

const transformAtUid = (graph = {}, uid = "", t = identity) =>
  recMapObject
    ( graph
    , (node = {}) =>
        node.uid === uid
          ? { ...node, data: t(node.data) }
          : node
    )
    
const data =
  {uid:"abc",layout:{rows:[{columns:[{blocks:[{uid:"bcd",data:{content:"how are you?"}}]},{blocks:[{uid:"cde",data:{content:"how are you?"}}]},],},{columns:[{blocks:[{uid:"def",data:{content:"how are you?"}}]}],}]}}

const result =
  transformAtUid
    ( data
    , "bcd"
    , node => ({ ...node, changed: "x" })
    )

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

---

In your original question, I see you have an array of objects to change -

```js
// your original
this.sections = [ {...}, {...}, ... ]
```

To use `recMapObject` and `transformAtUid` with an array of objects, we can use `Array.prototype.map` -

```js
this.sections = this.sections.map(o => transformAtUid(o, "bcd", ...))
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome back, Guest.  It's good to see you around these parts again, even with a different handle!  (Or am I totally off-base?)

Answer (score 1):

It can be simpler if use a queue:

```js
var sections = [
  {
    uid: "abc",
    layout: {
      rows: [
        {
          columns: [
            {
              blocks: [
                {
                  uid: "bcd",
                  data: {
                    content: "how are you?"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              blocks: [
                {
                  uid: "cde",
                  data: {
                    content: "how are you?"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          columns: [
            {
              blocks: [
                {
                  uid: "def",
                  data: {
                    content: "how are you?"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

var queue = [];
function trav(ss) {
  queue = queue.concat(ss);
  while (queue.length > 0) {
    tObj(queue.pop());
  }
  
  console.log("result", ss);
}

function tObj(obj) {
  if (obj.uid === "bcd") {
    obj.data = "new data";
  } else {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(el => {
      if (Array.isArray(obj[el])) {
        queue = queue.concat(obj[el]);
      } else if (typeof (obj[el]) === "object") {
        tObj(obj[el]);
      }
    });
  }
}



trav(sections);
```